# Is this an aldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

$\ce{CH3CH2CH2CHO}$
I think it is an aldehyde but I saw somewhere that it might be an alcohol...

I believe that it looks like this. Is that correct?
[image]

Comment: that's an aldehyde

Comment: In an alcohol, the alcohol group would be indicated as OH in a properly written formula.

Comment: yeah that's an aldehyde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an aldehyde as it contains ($\ce{-CHO}$) group.

Its not an alcohol because in alcohol the carbon and oxygen bond in a single (sigma) bond whereas in aldehyde it is a double bond.

$\ce{CH3CH2CH2CHO}$ cant be a alcohol because as you can see that the terminal carbon is attached to only 3 groups ($\ce{C}$, $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{O}$) which means that it is still missing 1 bond to complete its octet. Therefore this carbon makes one more bond, a double bond, with the oxygen atom to complete its octet and the oxygen also attains a complete octet by this.